# How to get fling on activity and onClickListener on button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an xml layout with buttons in relative layout. I want the layout to react on fling. I added a  linear layout as last child of a relative layout and it covered the whole screen and then I added onTouch in it to get the fling. The problem is that it never gets to the onclick listener on buttons (which is under the linear layout) but when I make the touch listener to return false my button gets called but the fling does not. How to get both of the events?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img_calendar" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/child"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img_child" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ball"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/child"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img_ball" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img_logo" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img_logo_second" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_information" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    ></LinearLayout>
```

```
public class GestureListener extends Activity{

    OnTouchListener toach_listener_cell = new OnTouchListener() {
        int id = 0;
        View v = null;
        View previous_for_singleTap_View = null;
        GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplication(),
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                         Toast.makeText(GestureListener.this, "DoubleTap",
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return super.onDoubleTap(e);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                         if(v.getId()==R.id.info)
                             test();
                         else if(v.getId()==R.id.linear)
                         Toast.makeText(GestureListener.this,
                         "singleLn", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                        /* Toast.makeText(GestureListener.this,
                         "onLongPress", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                        return false;
                    };
                });

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            id = v.getId();
            this.v = v;
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    };
    LinearLayout check;

    public void test(){
        Toast.makeText(GestureListener.this,
                 "info", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
        check=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);

        ImageView info=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.info);

        check.setOnTouchListener(toach_listener_cell);
        info.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                test();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: fling? what fling? do you mean `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener#onFling` ? if so, nobody can see your code...

Comment: Now you can see @pskink

Comment: add some logging code inside `onTouch` and see when it is called

Comment: singleTap/ doubletap not working i already tried.